# Asynchronous executing @Aspect class or JPA event observer

Tags: java, spring, jpa, asynchronous

Is that possible to execute methods annotated as @After (in class annotated as @Aspec) asynchronous? For example using annotation @Async or implements Runnable or Callable. And the same question for methods annotated as @PostPersist.

The real case is sending mail after registration. I don't want to execute method from some MailService in register method because this service will have too many dependencies and will be difficult to testing. But sending mail have to be executed asynchronous because this operation is very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Should not be a problem. Just start a new thread in the method "after" method.

AOP works as follows (by default):

When you register a bean that requires some aspects to be applied to, Spring creates a proxy around that bean and when you get the bean from the application context(by `ctx.getBean(MyBean.class)` or by `Autowire` is somewhere) you receive the proxy that has the real/target bean inside.

So, for example, when you tell Spring to execute a method after some target method this happens:

1. the application calls the method of the proxy
2. If something has to be executed before the target method(like configured `@Before` action) it's done.
3. call the real/target method
4. If something has to be executed after the target method(like configured `@After` action) it's done.
5. The next method in the call stack is executed

So basically with @After you just "insert" a method in the call stack. You can start a new thread from there, it will return the control immediately and the next thing after the target method will be executed.